# Sudo apt update not working "The list of sources could not be read."

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04

My turminal showing

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft.gpg != 

E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I have tried

```
sudo rm  /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft.gpg
```

Output:

```
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft.gpg': No such file or directory
```

also

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list
```

output:

```
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list': No such file or directory
```

last

```
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

gives output

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419)]/ jammy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

help me to fix it

Comment: What is the output of `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? Please copy that into your question and format it as code (use tripple backtics on a line above and below it) instead of an image. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my question,can u please check it again?

Comment: Please add output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`